# count of products search in categories

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display the category name without repeating and the number of products found in the given categories  in my application.I was able to see a list of product categories that we searched but could not handle the number of products. The category list is in the variable: EnableCategories for example:
Search phrase: Asus
PC(2)
Laptops(1)
My ViewModel:

```
 public class ProductListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> EnableCategories { get; set; }
    public int CountProduct { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> SaleProduct { get; set; }
    public Product DetailsProduct { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<Product>Products{ get; set; }
    public string CurrentCategory{ get; set; }


}
```

My controler:

```
 public ActionResult SearchProduct(string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
        int pageSize = 1;
        int pageNumber = page ?? 1;

        var products = productRepository.Products.Where(s => s.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())).ToList();
        var categories = products.Where(s => s.CategoryID == s.Category.CategoryID).ToList();

        var vm = new ProductListViewModel()
        {
            EnableCategories = categories,
            Products = products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)
         };

        return View(vm);
    }
```

and View:

```
@model TechCom.App.Models.ProductListViewModel
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;
@using System.Linq
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SearchProduct";
}
    @foreach (var item in Model.EnableCategories)
    {
        <a href="@Url.Action("ProductList","Product", new{ 
        categoryName=item.Category.CategoryName,currentFilter = 
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter})">
        @item.Category.CategoryName </a>
       <br />

    }


@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{

    @Html.Partial("_ProductList", item)

}
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Products, page => Url.Action("SearchProduct", new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```